# Java object configuration with html

Tags: java, html

I have a java objects (pojo) that represernts my configuration.
I am reading them from xml files using jaxb and writing them also.

I want to allow users of my web application to edit those configuration objects.

Is there a way to do it?
I mean create html from the objects, show them to user while allowing modification and pass it back to the server?
Is there a framework that will generate html form for editing?

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a question which is basically asking for a standard CRUD framework, although perhaps the asker doesn't realise that. If you're going to downvote, at least explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm personally using the Play! Framework for something similar. We have a set of POJOs that can be created/edited in a web app form and are then stored in our database through JPA. We then query the database and marshal the objects as XML for other purposes.

Since you tagged this as Java, it'll be worth noting that this can be done in either Scala or Java as the Play! Framework supports both, though the HTML helpers are provided in Scala, it might still be worth a look at from you.

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/Home